# Change encoding of an uploaded folder in Django to "uft-8"

Tags: python, django

I am building a django application where I upload a folder containing a lot of CSV files.

I retrieve the folder like this in HTML and it works fine:

```
 <div class="upload_csv">
        <h2>Upload</h2>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="file" name="folder" multiple="true" webkitdirectory="true" 
        directory="true"/>
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
 </div>
```

Now, the problem is that I need to use "utf-8" encoding before moving on. I dont know how to do that when handling a directory with CSV files. What I have so far is this:

```
def csv_retriever(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['folder']:
       # encoding could happen here with the entire folder           

       for file in request.FILES.getlist('folder'):
           # or here with the current file 
           calculations(file)

    return render(request, 'price_calculator_started.html')
```